# Groovy unexpected token @

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, xsd, field

I'm having trouble with part of code below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "acct",
  "dateFrom",
  "dateTo"
})
```

startup failed:

> portal.view.[***].getAccStmtList.GetAcctStmtList.groovy: 403: unexpected token: @ @ line 403, column 1.
>   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD).

In same objects, `XmlAccessorType` works correctly. Here is my code.

```
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "schCrit"
})

@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "newCrit"
})
```

Comment: Problem solved, I changed all {} in object to arrays [] and object was compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the syntactical differences between Groovy and Java is with declaring [arrays literals](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_array_initializers). As such, the String array value of the `propOrder` element needs to be written with square brackets instead of curly braces:

```
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = [
  "acct",
  "dateFrom",
  "dateTo"
])
```